# How to translate "to wait for" in Russian

Tags: перевод

I am trying to understand how to use the verb хдать in Russian. According to wiktionary it wants the genitive, so for example, to translate "I am waiting for Vladimir at the restaurant" I would say

> Я жду Владимира в ресторане

And this is also confirmed by Google Translator. But, if I want to say "I am waiting for Natasha", Google Translator uses the accusative:

> Я жду Наташу в ресторане

It seems that with masculine and neutral nouns Google Translator uses the genitive, while with female nouns it uses the accusative.

I know that for animate masculine nouns, the accusative is the same as the genitive, so Владимира can be either accusative or genitive. But if I translate "I wait for the milk" the translation is

> Я жду молока в ресторане

where молока is definitely genitive.

So my question is: is it correct that ждать wants the genitive with masculine and neutral nouns and the accusative with female nouns?

(I also tried to look at context reverso, but it was not able to clear my confusion)

Comment: In *я жду Владимира*, the object is in accusative as well (the two forms coincide for this word)

Comment: But as I said, if I translate "I am waiting for the milk" I get "я жду молока", where молока is clearly a genitive.

Comment: yes and the linked answer has the explanation for that. Is there something missing in that answer? If there is please update your question and I'll reopen it. Thanks!